# Example of the symmetry breaking and the unchanged charge commutation in the current algebra

Tags: lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking

In the current algebra by J.D. BJORKEN, https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.ns.18.120168.001305 discussed the origin of the current algebra. The paper said  Gell-Mann

> In attempting to interpret in precise terms the notion of a symmetr)
> violated by the strong interactions, Gell-Mann suggested that the S U(3)
> symmetry operators be identified with the charges associated with the weak
> interaction currents. In particular, he emphasized the equal-time commutation relations of these charges, pointing out that they may remain unchanged
> even in the presence of symmetry breaking, and showing how this leads to a
> precise concept of universality of the weak interaction.

What did the context mean by the symmetry breaking? [The current algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_algebra) on the Wikipedia was

$$[V^a(\vec x),V^b(\vec y)]=f^{ab}_c \delta(\vec x-\vec y)V^c(\vec x)$$

$$[V^a(\vec x),A^b(\vec y)]=f^{ab}_c \delta(\vec x-\vec y)A^c(\vec x)$$

$$[A^a(\vec x),A^b(\vec y)]=f^{ab}_c \delta(\vec x-\vec y)V^c(\vec x)$$

But it's hard to see where the "charges" would come up unchanged, (since $V$ and $A$ were both the current and the commutation was defined with respect to the current, not the charges), and how it could connect to the symmetry breaking.

Could you provide an example to explain the context, please?

*There was some definition in the Eq. 2.6 to Eq. 2.9, but the naming was different. a. $V^\pm$ and $V^3$ in Eq. 2.9 seemed to correspond to Eq.2.10, so the "current" $V^a$ was actually "charges"?(An English manipulation?) But there wasn't the mention of what the operator $A$ or the "axial charge densities" $U$ correspond to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question probably belongs to [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com),
as it probably tries to reconstruct the frame of mind of the physics theory community in the late 60s, before the advent of the EW standard model and QCD, both of which triumphantly vindicated current algebra.

In any case, Gell-Mann correctly (virtually magically!) intuited that group theory underlay the physics picture, "as though" there was a QFT theory of fermions (quarks and leptons) operative underneath, with little tweaks which could provide corrections to the 0th approximation; and that the canonical equal-time current commutators of it would yield correct expressions for both strong and electromagnetic and weak couplings. This piece of agnostic "old physics" survived the introduction of the SM to a "t", indeed virtually led to it!

Here is the setup. A charge is the space integral of the 0th component of the corresponding Noether current, $$Q^a= \int d^3x ~~V^a_0(\vec x).$$ For a conserved current, this construction yields a time-independent charge, $dQ^a/dt=0$, but not necessarily so for a non-conserved current. So these 0 components are essentially current densities. You skipped the 0 Lorentz subscripts in your question.

You may then see that
$$[V^a_0(\vec x),V^b_0(\vec y)]=f^{ab}_c \delta(\vec x-\vec y)V^c_0(\vec x)~~~\leadsto \\
[Q^a,V^b_0(\vec y)]=f^{ab}_c  V^c_0(\vec y) ~~~\leadsto \\
[Q^a,Q^b]=f^{ab}_c  Q^c .
$$
The last equation is (2.20) of your review article.

Now these charges are not quite conserved (because of quark mass differences, as we now know, and was suspected all along back then), so this SU(3) symmetry is violated, but current algebra relations helped quantify the violation in systematic ways--the genius of flavor SU(3) symmetry ("violated by the strong interactions") breaking patterns.

Moreover, the axial currents $A^a_\mu$ obeying the full algebra you wrote are instrumental in describing axial charges involved in chiral symmetry (also explicitly broken by quark masses, but, more significantly, *further* spontaneously broken as a consequence of the strong interactions, nowadays dubbed "Nambu-Goldstone realization of the symmetry").

These currents, in contrast to the electromagnetic ones, are only *partially conserved*. Moreover, the *V-A* combinations look and feel and behave like the currents coupling to the weak interactions.
(And ***are*** those, we are now sure!).

As a consequence the exact canonical current algebra for even non conserved currents is stunningly useful in connecting weak and strong interaction amplitudes normally involving couplings of photons, charged weak currents, and strong pion amplitudes  among themselves! At the time, physicists found this exhilarating, and it set up the scene for the SM, with the advent of asymptotic freedom, QCD, and the Weinberg-Salam electroweak theory. The SM was built on the foundation of current algebra.

(At the time, there were comical metaphors about QFT serving as slices of ham to bake pheasant steaks between, and then discarded, etc..., all kinds of evasions to mask the puzzlement of theorists w.r.t. an asymptotic freedom they hardly suspected existed...)

The formulas you are alluding to in your last paragraph relate to lepton, not quark currents, which follow suit similarly.